# Ratio of $F_{net}$ acting on a body to its weight?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, acceleration

[image]

> The acceleration of a body, expressed as a multiple of $g$, is $always$ equal to the ratio of the net force on the body to its weight.

What does this statement mean? Is it referring to the g-force acting on a body? But that equals net force acting on the body divided by its mass (force acting per unit mass). I don’t quite understand the highlighted statement.

That’s Page no. 120 from the book ‘University Physics with Modern Physics’, 13th edition.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Newton's 2nd law:
\begin{align}
F_\text{net} &= ma\\
\therefore\quad F_\text{net} &= ma\,\frac{g}{g}\\
\therefore\quad \frac{F_\text{net}}{mg} &= \frac{a}{g}
\end{align}
where $g\approx 9.8$ ms$^{-2}$ is the acceleration due to (Earth's) gravity.